# Spark streaming - textFileStream/fileStream - Get file name

Tags: java, apache-spark

Using spark streaming I am watching for the files in HDFS using `textFileStream/fileStream` methods, how do we get the `fileNames` which are read by these methods?

I used `textFileStream` which has file contents in `JavaDStream` and I got no success with `fileStream` as it is throwing me a compilation error with spark version 1.3.1.

Can someone please tell me if we have an API function or any other way to get the file names that these streaming methods read?

Thanks 
Lokesh

Comment: What is the compilation error? I guess you did not do it right with the `InputFormat`. From what I learned from the functions in `DStream`, I really don't think you can get the file name :(

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, regarding the compilation error. I have posted the same in spark forum in the below link. http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-1-3-1-JavaStreamingContext-fileStream-compile-error-td22683.html

Comment: Hi DavidShen You were correct I was using TextInputFormat from a different package. When I used the right one I was able to get this method working.

Comment: Hi Lokesh, can you please highlight the solution and the correct package name?   Refer this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076339/sparkstreaming-error-in-filestream

Comment: Hi I have replied to the above link in the answer section, the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076339/sparkstreaming-error-in-filestream