# Spark Streaming textFileStream watch output of RDD.saveAsTextFile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Running Spark 1.6.2 (YARN mode)

Firstly, I have some code from this post to [get filenames within Spark Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031276/spark-streaming-dstream-rdd-to-get-file-name), so that could be the issue, but hopefully not.

Basically, I have this first job.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{StreamingContext, Seconds}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

def getStream(ssc: StreamingContext, dir: String): DStream[String] = {
    ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](dir)
}

val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

val inputDir = "hdfs:///tmp/input"
val outputDir = "hdfs:///tmp/output1"

val stream1 = getStream(ssc, inputDir)
stream1.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.saveAsTextFile(outputDir))

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

And I also have a second job that, for this example, looks practically identical, just change around `inputDir` and `outputDir`, and move to a new `outputDir = "hdfs:///tmp/output2"`.

Anyway, so I have to start the second streaming job before the first job because it needs to watch for new files. Makes sense...

Then, I start the first job and `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal` some files into the input folder since per the API

> Files must be written to the monitored directory by "moving" them from another location within the same file system. File names starting with . are ignored.

When I try to run this, it eventually crashes with a stacktrace that contains this

```
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 7 ms
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1485949715000 ms:
hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/output1/_SUCCESS
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 355.9 KB, free 356.8 KB)
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 28.9 KB, free 385.7 KB)
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:43097 (size: 28.9 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from fileStream at FileStreamTransformer.scala:45
17/02/01 11:48:35 ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time 1485949715000 ms
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/output1/_SUCCESS
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:120)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream$$anonfun$4.apply(FileInputDStream.scala:276)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream$$anonfun$4.apply(FileInputDStream.scala:266)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.org$apache$spark$streaming$dstream$FileInputDStream$$filesToRDD(FileInputDStream.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.compute(FileInputDStream.scala:153)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.compute(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(TransformedDStream.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.compute(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(TransformedDStream.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:115)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:251)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:182)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/output1/_SUCCESS
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:120)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream$$anonfun$4.apply(FileInputDStream.scala:276)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream$$anonfun$4.apply(FileInputDStream.scala:266)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.org$apache$spark$streaming$dstream$FileInputDStream$$filesToRDD(FileInputDStream.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.compute(FileInputDStream.scala:153)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.compute(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(TransformedDStream.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.compute(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(TransformedDStream.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:115)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:251)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:182)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO StreamingContext: Invoking stop(stopGracefully=false) from shutdown hook
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO JobGenerator: Stopping JobGenerator immediately
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO RecurringTimer: Stopped timer for JobGenerator after time 1485949715000
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO JobGenerator: Stopped JobGenerator
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO JobScheduler: Stopped JobScheduler
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/streaming,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/streaming/batch,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static/streaming,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO StreamingContext: StreamingContext stopped successfully
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/streaming/batch/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/streaming/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.17.0.2:4040
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-85bb28ad-e3e1-4b2a-8795-04ac1c6a0ea5
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-85bb28ad-e3e1-4b2a-8795-04ac1c6a0ea5/httpd-65e6e9f0-dcb8-4b66-86f6-f775e2e497c0
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
17/02/01 11:48:35 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
```

And I know that `_SUCCESS` file is being written by `rdd.saveAsTextFile`, so that's not the issue, but my issues are as follows:

1. The file **does** exist. Can see it using `hadoop fs -ls`
2. Even if the file didn't exist, the API is designed to pickup **new** files. Why is that being read?
3. That file is empty, so why should it be processed anyway?
4. Is this even possible? **Can Spark Streaming watch the output of another Spark job?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to explicitly enforce that only new files are processed and to ensure touch files liek _SUCCESS are skipped we can use the below signature of `fileStream`

```
def getStream(ssc: StreamingContext, dir: String): DStream[String] = {
   ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](dir,
      (path: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) => !path.getName.startsWith("_") || !path.getName().startsWith("."),
      newFilesOnly = true)
}
```

The newFileOnly defaults to true when not specified as shown [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.3/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/FileInputDStream.scala#L79). So ideally  `_SUCCESS` should not have been processed in your setup too.

Comment: I just noticed that parameter when reading over the API methods. I have yet to try. Side question: Is there any side-effect of `newFilesOnly = false` other than it picks up existing files? I am getting tired of moving files in and out of HDFS while testing this.

Comment: Also, I think I want to keep skipping the dot-files, so perhaps something like `getName.matches("^[^_.]")`?

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah.. I was updating that in my answer but without using regex... :)  if you use regex you will have to properly escape the dot operator

Comment: Not within a character class, I don't think.