# How to re-configure spark /hadoop to read files starting with an "_" (underscore)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr, hidden-files

I know that files starting with "_" and "." are hidden files. And the `hiddenFileFilter` will be always applied. It is added inside method `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus`

From research, I understood that we can use `FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter` to set our custom `PathFilter` and that the `hiddenFileFilter` is always active.

For this purpose I created a `MyPathFilter` class as follows:

```
class MyPathFilter implements PathFilter{
  public boolean accept(Path path) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return path.getName();
  }
}
```

and I know it should be used something like this before we read the input files:

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(job,MyPathFilter.class);
```

But the problem with my Spark/Scala based Data processing App/pipeline is that we are reading the files as text, as follows:

```
val spark = context.sparkSession
import spark.implicits._
val rawDF = spark.read
            .text(list: _*)
            .map { r =>
                    //do something
              }.toDF()
```

There is no way I can change how we are reading files because it is associated with capturing the metadata from the folders nested structure of the file location. So with `spark.read` staying intact, how can I make sure that I can also read the files with filename starting with "_" (underscore)? How to use `FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter` in this situation?

We run our jobs on AWS-EMR so can we parameterize the `FileInputFormat.SetInputPathFilter` while creating the EMR cluster? Or can we make use of `spark-submit` options to re-configure and turn the "read hidden files feature" ON?

Please help me with your valuable suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `spark.read.text`. Use the `hadoopRdd` functions. For example in streaming https://stackoverflow.com/a/41970307/2308683

Comment: Hi cricket_007, can you please help me on how to use hadoop rdd in my scenario? the streaming example is not that helpful? thank you in adavnce!

Comment: I've not written Spark code in years. I just remember using something similar to that other post to read those files.

Comment: Is there a SOLUTION for this question? Please link.